# Let $(X,A,\mu,T)$ be a measure preserving dynamical system. Equality of integrals after composing with $T$?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $(X, A, \mu)$ be a measure space, let $T:X \rightarrow X$ be a measure preserving map, and let $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an $L^1$ function. Is it true that for any measurable subset $B \subset X$, $$\int_B f \ d\mu = \int_{T^{-1}(B)} f \circ T \ d\mu \ ?$$ If so, hints on how to prove it would be preferred over full solutions. If it isn't true, are there any additional reasonable hypotheses that would make it true? So far I know it's true when $f$ is an $L^1$ simple function, but I haven't seen a way to make the leap to all $L^1$ functions yet.

Comment: Sorry to say that any hint will almost give away the solution since there is only one idea involved here.

Comment: OK, I get it now! For some reason I thought you didn't have the usual notions of convergence because the domain is not a topological space, now I see that $X$ could be an arbitrary set and pointwise convergence is still well defined; at this point it becomes obvious. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a natural transition of showing to positive $L^1$ functions and then deducing from linearity of the integral, that it is true for general $L^1$ functions.

To show this for positive $L^1$ functions, you know by the simple function approximation theorem that there exists a sequence of simple functions, $\{ \phi_n \}_{n=1}^\infty$, to $f$. The equality holds for each of them and there is equality of the limit by either the DCT or MCT.